# Bash script to text watermark video from filename (ffmpeg)

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I would like to automate some text to be 'watermarked' on my videos. Basically I want to create a marker in my file names (eg "&&"). Then I want the script to take the content after "&&" and place it in the "drawtext" content.

For example, file named "Video2132 && The First Test" would make the part after "text=" become "The First Test".

The below code works fine without the drawtext part.

As soon as I add that function, the script runs, but it creates empty video files (zero bytes).

```
for f in ./*.mov; do
    printf '%s\n' "Doing stuff with: ${f}"

    i='0'
    while (( i <= 5 )); do
        ffmpeg -ss "$(( i * 25 ))" -t 25 -i "${f}" -acodec copy -vf drawtext="fontfile=/Users/mac1/Library/Fonts/Gillsanslight.ttf: \
text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: \
boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy "${f%.mov}.${i}.mov" -loglevel quiet
        (( i++ ))
    done
done
```

Comment: Share the console output. You'll have to change the loglevel to `info` or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the file name to a variable and replace the `FILENAME PART` to your file name variable.

You didn't specify the where is the name `Video2132 && The First Test` come from.

```
$file_name=$(echo "Video2132 && The First Test" |sed 's/^.*&& //') # TODO, extract the name
```

then change the filter from

```
drawtext="fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='FILENAME PART':fontcolor=red@1.0:fontsize=70:x=00:y=40"
```

to

```
drawtext="fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf:text='"$file_name"':fontcolor=red@1.0:fontsize=70:x=00:y=40"
```

Comment: Thanks alijandro, but this hasn't worked. I think your bash is right- but ffmpeg still creates empty files. I think this is because ffmpeg need to re-encode the video to add text to it (it can't just copy). Can you adjust my example to re-encode (not just copy)?

Comment: Your video stream is not copied. You didn't specify the options `-vcodec copy` or `-codec:v copy`. Make sure these two options `-ss` start offset and `-t` duration are valid for your video. Also, the `-acodec copy` and `-codec:a copy` have the same meaning. Pick either of them is enough.